# How to use a constructor that already exists?

Tags: java, android, firebase, constructor, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a simple app for children with Firebase and I'm constantly getting this error:

```
Android Firebase Database exception: not define a no-argument constructor
```

I have a class Activities and two other helper classes HomeActivities and OutsideActivities. This is my code for my classes:

```
public class Activities {
    private String type;
    private int count;

    public Activities() { }

    public Activities(String type, int count) {
        this.type = type;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    class HomeActivities {
        private String name;
        private int noOfChildren;

        HomeActivities() { }

        public HomeActivities(String name, int noOfChildren) {
            this.name = name;
            this.noOfChildren = noOfChildren;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getNoOfChildren() {
            return noOfChildren;
        }

        public void setNoOfChildren(int noOfChildren) {
            this.noOfChildren = noOfChildren;
        }
    }

    class OutsideActivities {
        private String name;
        private int noOfChildren;

        public OutsideActivities() { }

        public OutsideActivities(String name, int noOfChildren) {
            this.name = name;
            this.noOfChildren = noOfChildren;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getNoOfChildren() {
            return noOfChildren;
        }

        public void setNoOfChildren(int noOfChildren) {
            this.noOfChildren = noOfChildren;
        }
    }
}
```

Please see all the constructors. Even if I already have defined the correct constructor in each class, I get this error. How to solve this? Please help me.

Comment: Do `HomeActivities` and `OutSideActivities` need to be an inner class of `Activities`? Can you change them to a `static class`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two methods in which you can get rid of this error.

1. Make both inner classes `static`.
2. Make both inner classes `independent` (each class in it's own separte file).

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Constructor of HomeActivities() has default visibility. public keyword is missed. Database ORM provider can't instantiate objects when the constructor is not public.

Should be:

```
class HomeActivities {
    private String name;
    private int noOfChildren;

    public HomeActivities() { }
```

All other suggestions are valid as well. You should externalize classes in separate files.